# Avoid slider being resized when adding a picture

Tags: html, css

I am making a slider with this basis https://codepen.io/naomilea/pen/XjbXVE

I want to add other pictures and when I add a picture that has another size than the already added pictures the whole slider changes in size. Is there a way to avoid this to happen or resize the images to the already added images?

I am trying to resize the images in CSS. 
I've adjusted the HTML to suite me better but not changed the CSS anything

Here is the HTML

```
    <div id=slides>
        <div id=overflow>
            <div class=inner>
                <article>
                    <img src="aboutuscoffee.jpg" />
                </article>
                <article>
                    <img src="#"/>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <img src=http://csscience.com/responsiveslidercss3/MountainOutpostByBjzaba.png />
                </article>
                <article>
                    <img src=http://csscience.com/responsiveslidercss3/CliffsByBjzaba.png />
                </article>
            </div>
```

Comment: You can set height or width fix in image tag.

Comment: you have to use, all the slider images of same **resolution**

Comment: You can set `min-width` and `max-width` for `<img>`.